# Base64'ed Unicode font icons not rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts, base64, font-face

I'm having a problem getting unicode characters to render in any browser via a Base64-encoded FontAwesome font file. Normal ascii characters display just fine, and I can see in Chrome the font is successfully loaded from the Base64 in my .css:

[image]

When adding a :before and a matching unicode character, the font's character is not being found. f083 should be the camera icon in font awesome - http://fontawesome.io/icon/camera-retro/

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "TestF";
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2'),
         url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

div {
    font-family: "TestF" !important;
}

div:before {
    content: "\f083";
}
```

[image]

This is occurring on both Chrome and IE (10). Do unicode characters not get included when turning a font into Base64? (I have been using the FontSquirrel encoder to create the Base64).

Comment: Maybe your encoded font-family is wrong, capitals and everything?

Comment: If that was the case, I would assume other fonts would not render. I've tried running other non-standard fonts through it which contain ASCII characters, and the Base64 successfully renders my 'Hello' in that font.

Comment: Serious question: why are you BASE64'ing a font that is used in so many places it's actually more likely your users have it cached than not? BASE64 makes the font take up 33% more bytes, AND you're forcing users to download all of them, not just the ones supported by their browser, by inlining the BASE64 string. Also, why are you using font squirrel for a font that already has CDN hosting in every format needed on the web? Nothing about this approach makes sense... =S

Comment: Running into a CORS issue that we have zero control over the destination server and zero control to alter the header prior to it being sent. We are also not guaranteed internet access (possibly only intranet) to use CDN hosting. Believe me... we tried to get around it for days with no luck.

Comment: That sounds a hell of a lot like an XY problem though. There should be no reason to run into CORS if you use put the font on your own server, for instance (as it'll be a normal request). The biggest problem with BASE64 is that this becomes a massive blocking resource load: your CSS file needs to transfer *and then parse* both fonts (both of which have been made 1/3rd larger in bytesize), not just one, before the browser even sees any CSS rules. So instead I'd highly recommend you ask a new question about your CORS problem, specific to loading fonts, with details on what happens hosting locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting an entire day, I figured out I'm stupid...

Make sure your data:application/font-[filetype] actually matches the file you converted to Base64. FontSquirrel only takes in ttfs, so of course it won't work taking a ttf encoded string in as a woff.